# issues with printf and exponential formatting

Tags: php, printf

After re reading [printf](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) docs, I wanted to give a try to `%g` attribute.  If I'm working with two digits what can go wrong, right?

```
php -r "echo printf('%g', 123.4000);"
123.45     // What? 
php -r "echo printf('%g', 123.4500);"
123.456    // This can't be right
php -r "echo printf('%g', '123.4000');"
123.45
```

I was expecting 123.4 or even 1234e-1. So, where's my guessing wrong?

Comment: The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `sprintf` with echo, `printf` outputs number of printed chars.
So

```
string sprintf ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )
int printf ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )
```

Or you can rewrite your code to `php -r "printf('%g', '123.4000');"`

Comment: You're right. I was so focus on the %g part that didn't notice the function I was using